# C# UWP How to change content control background from another process?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, uwp

Using Win32 API I know is possible to change the background of a window from another thread / process, walk the visual three (child items) and alter various properties of child controls (WinForms windows for example). I managed to change the window background of a UWP Window (after finding its Hwnd). It is possible to alter the background brush of a control which is the content of that window (for example a SplitView)?

Comment: There is no supported way of changing a window's drawing resources from another process.

Answer (score 0):

> change the background of a window from another thread / process

UWP UI-interface can only be changed in UI-thread, you need to set the background property in UI-Thread. As Raymond Chen said  there is no supported way of changing a window's drawing resources from another process. but UWP support [`AppService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) communication, so you could send a message flag from a UWP app to the destination UWP app that registered AppService then notify it change the background. And  if the control client is desktop app, it need to launched with [`FullTrustProcessLauncher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-19041).